# Bootstrap collapse menu not scrolling on touch

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, touch

I'm working on building a mobile nav menu using Bootstrap's collapse menu option and it opens/closes fine on both mobile and web but won't allow me to scroll on mobile when I'm using touch.

When I open the menu in the emulator I can scroll it with my mouse but if I use the emulator's click and drag, it doesn't move. Same goes if I push to production and test on mobile. Instead of scrolling the menu it's scrolling the body content behind the menu.

I can only confirm on iPhone for now because I haven't tried Android, but it's for sure not working on touch on iPhone.

I've tried raising the z-index to see if it was a layering issue, I've tried eliminating the max-height, I've even tried this https://www.gaslampmedia.com/multilevel-dropdown-menus-bootstrap-3-x/, which is supposed to solve all multi-level problems.

Nothing has worked.

**////// UPDATES //////**

1/11 @1:42PM: Just figured out I can get it to scroll on touch in the emulator by adding "max-height: none" to the "#navbar-collapse" styling — still not working when I push to production server and test on iPhone though.

Here's my HTML/PHP

```
<nav id="mobile-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id="js-menu-icon" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- <a href="/">
                <div class="mobile-logo"></div>
            </a>
            <div id="header-search-wrap-mobile" class="header-extra-btn">
                <a href="#" class="block-link" id="header-search-btn-mobile">
                    <form action="/" method="get" id="site-search-form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=" Site Search" name="s" id="search" class="site-search-mobile focus">
                        <button class="submit-search" type="submit" id="submit-search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="mobile-search-submit"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </a>
            </div> -->              
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu'=> 'Main Nav', 'depth' => 2, 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse', 'container_id' => 'navbar-collapse', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav', 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback', 'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()) ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Ignore the comments, that has (or shouldn't) no effect on the dropdown, it's all in the header above the menu.

Not sure if it has anything to do with the nav items being loaded in php, but I assume it shouldn't be?

Also, I'm using this WordPress theme, if that helps http://pol-demo1.gogetthemes.com/?page_id=600

And here's what the code looks like after rendered in browser. Can get more screenshots if necessary!

[image]

Comment: What does the code look like on the client after it's served and the PHP is rendered?

Comment: Just uploaded a screenshot @Monkpit.. let me know if you need anything else

Comment: It is a multi-level nav, which may be causing issues from what I've been reading. Any insight on that?

Comment: Multi-level nav works great with touch in the Chrome mobile emulator on the demo of the theme you linked.

Comment: Ya I know.. I picked up this project after a couple other devs were on it for a few months and now trying to undo their work.. doesn't look to me like they're using Bootstrap on the theme site tho. Not seeing any of the class/id names necessary at least